# Dynamic Soql throwing an error

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

```
String str = 'hellotest';
String qry = 'select id,Products__c from Account where End_Date__c > :system.today() and Start_Date__c < :system.today() and IsValid__c = true and Approved__c =' + '\'' + 'Yes' + '\'';
        //order by createddate desc
        if(!str.equals('NoPromo')){
            qry = qry + ' and teststr__c = :str' ;
            qry = qry + ' and Offer_Type__c ='  + '\'' + 'Promo Code Campaign' + '\'';
        }
            qry = qry + ' order by createddate desc';
            system.debug(qry);
                for(Account pc: Database.Query(qry)){}
```

When i am trying to execute the above logic it is throwing the error

> System.QueryException: unexpected token: '('

Can someone please help me where i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use complex Apex binds (expressions like `System.today()`) in Dynamic SOQL. Dynamic SOQL only support simple binds to Apex variables.

Assign the dates you need to use to Apex variables, e.g.,

```
Date today = System.today();
```

and then bind to those variables:

```
where End_Date__c > :today
```